# do not allow to reload the page when popup is started with javascript

Tags: javascript, popup, reload

Hy,

i've got verry strange behavior (at least, i think it's strange...)

I've got a page where users can pick a color for background and a color for the text.

I've found a color picker on the internet, and that's working all just fine...

But every time i open the popup, the page reload. To test this i added a alert in script tags, and i got the alert when i acces the page and when i open the popup...

This is verry annoying, because the changes that users made will be lost ever time they open the popup...

Here is the button that fires the popup:

```
<button onclick="PopUp(\'background\')">gebruik de color picker</button>
```

note that this is part of a php string, so that's why the single quotes are escaped....

and this is the function PopUp:

```
function PopUp(keuze){
    if(keuze == 'background'){
        $('#clicked_one').val('background');
        var de_waarde = $('#background_keuze').val();
        $('#clicked_value').val(de_waarde);
    }
    else if(keuze == 'text'){
        $('#clicked_one').val('text');
        var de_waarde = $('#text_keuze').val();
        $('#clicked_value').val(de_waarde);
    }
    window.open( './popup_color_picker.php', '_blank', 'width=500,height=500');
}
```

The popup page:

```
<?php
include '../config.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Color Picker</title>
        <script src="<?php echo $root_off_page; ?>javascript/color_picker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" class="color" id="color" value="">
        <button onclick="klaar()">deze kleur wordt het</button>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    var wat_is_geklikt = opener.document.getElementById('clicked_one').value;
    var de_juiste_waarde = opener.document.getElementById('clicked_value').value;

    function klaar(){
        var de_gekozen_kleur = document.getElementById('color').value;
        if(wat_is_geklikt == 'background'){
            opener.document.getElementById('background_keuze').value = de_gekozen_kleur;
        }
        else if(wat_is_geklikt == 'text'){
            opener.document.getElementById('text_keuze').value = de_gekozen_kleur;
        }

        self.close()
    }

</script>
```

So does anybody see the problem why the main page (the opener) reloads???

Thanks

Comment: Is the button wrapped in a form?

Comment: This combination of Dutch, English, HTML, PHP, and Javascript is screwing with mijn verstanding of taalen.

Comment: @MikeRobinson so true...

Comment: @Andreas ,yes, the button is in a form. this is the code for the form: <form method="POST"> nothing more nothing less... (this is the right way to lead the post to itself right???)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default type of a button (if omitted) is submit which causes the reload of your page. Just change the type to button

```
<button type="button" onclick="PopUp(\'background\')">gebruik de color picker</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with an < a > tag, I added type="button" to that and it fixed my issue, thanks for the help!